# Updating item in List B when item in List A is updated (using workflow)

Tags: designer-workflow, item-updating

I have two list (one in List section and second is a document in Library). Both Lists have the same columns. When an item in the Lista A is updated, corresponding item in List B would be updated. How to achieve this?

Thank you for your tips!

Comment: MORE PRECISELY: I have one list in List section and document library with template document. When an item is created in the list new Word document in document Library appears (data from the new item fullfill the Word template and this new Word document appers- and it is a workflow on creation the Word document in Library). Now i would like to make workflow on updating this Word-document, when the corresponding item is updated in the List,

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with the second list is a "document in a library"? Is it a Sharepoint list or a independent file? If it is a SP list, you can easily build a workflow triggered at any change in the A list and copying the modified data into the B list.

List workflow based on A list:

- update item in list B (you have to specify the "hook" in the 'Find List Item', the field the WF has to update in the B list) based on the value of current item (A list)
- [End of workflow]
- set the start option to workflow to "start workflow automatically when an item is changed"

That's all

M

Comment: Marpio,i have one list in List section and document library with template document. When an item is created in the list new Word document in document Library appears (data from the new item fullfill the Word template and this new Word document appers- and it is a workflow on creation the Word document in Library). Now i would like to make workflow on updating this Word-document, when the corresponding item is updated in the List,